# Bounding the discrete l2 norm for polynomials.

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Given the polynomial space $\Pi_d^n$ which contains all the d-variable polynomials of degree up to $n$ and some scattered points $X\subset \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ ($\Omega$ is an open subset).

Since $\Pi_d^n$ is finite dimensional space there must be a constant $C$ such that

$ \left\|p\right\|_{l_2(X)}\leq C\left\|p\right\|_{L_2}  $  for all   $p\in\Pi_d^n$

where $\left\|p\right\|^2_{l_2(X)} = \frac{1}{|X|}\sum_{x\in X} p(x)^2$ and $\left\|p\right\|^2_{L_2} = \int_{\Omega} p(x)^2dx$.

Is it possible to find the constant $C$? Or at least gauge some understanding into how $C$ depends on $\Omega$, $X$, $n$ and $d$?

Thanks.

Comment: One could also consider $$\|p\|_\mu^2 = \int_\Omega p(x)^2\,d\mu(x)$$ for other Borel probability measures $\mu$ on $\Omega$.  You have two extreme cases.  Are they extreme?


Comment: Not sure my comment is actually helping, but what do you mean by "what C depends on"? I guess $C$ depends on $\Omega$, $X$, $n$ and $d$.

Comment: It seems more reasonable that $C$ doesn't depend on the exact location of the scattered points $X$ but instead on the fill distance of $X$ in $\Omega$. I was hoping for some idea of how the constant depends on $\Omega$, $X$, $n$ and $d$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is possible to gain some understanding at least understand rough bounds. I will just consider the case $d = 1$. First observe that
$$
 \|p\| _{\ell^2(X)} \leq \|p\| _{\infty}.
$$
Second we have on can  always choose a one point set $X$, depending on $p$ such that equality holds. Next, one can derive for $\Omega$ an interval bounds on $\|p\| _{\infty}$ from $\|p\|_2$ using the inequality
$$
 |p'(x)| \leq \frac{n}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} \|p\| _{L^{\infty}([-1,1])}
$$
(I hope I remember the constants correctly). Versions for several intervals can be found in an Acta paper by V. Totik (around 2000).

So what one gets in this case is that $C ~ n |I|$.